# Java Getting String from another class returning null

Tags: java, string, null

I currently have two constructors in one of my classes, one going to my main class, and the other to another class that has most of the methods that I use. The reason I don't use static methods for my second class that I have a constructor, is that I don't want the code to be used by any other source, just mine. Here are the two constructors:

```
PrisonProfessionalMain plugin;

public PPCommandAdminMenu(PrisonProfessionalMain instance)
{
    plugin = instance;
}

QuickMethods qm;
public PPCommandAdminMenu(QuickMethods instance)
{
    qm = instance;
}
```

Then I am calling a method from the `QuickMethods` class here:

```
qm.getConfigString(plugin, "prefix")
```

Apparently, whatever method I call from this class it returns null. I do not think it is what I put inside of the method, but here is the method from the other class:

```
public String getConfigString(PrisonProfessionalMain instance, String configvar)
{
    return colorize(instance.getConfig().getString(configvar));
}
```

I don't see a problem here, but I am wondering if I should use a static way instead. I want to try and stay away from static methods for the reason I stated above.

REMEMBER: Calling any other method from this class results in it returning null. I know this because in console it has a stack trace that reads it null. It says this on the line that is calling any method from this class.

I tried removing the Strings and instances from inside the method:

```
public String getConfigString()
{
    return System.out.println("test");
}
```

This still however, resulted in another null pointer, pointing at the line that I called the method on.

My question is: How would I have the QuickMethods class stop returning null upon calling methods/strings from it.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: @DoNhuVy better now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only one constructor can be called at a time, given your code it appears you need to combine your constructors like,

```
QuickMethods qm;
PrisonProfessionalMain plugin;
public PPCommandAdminMenu(PrisonProfessionalMain plugin, QuickMethods qm)
{
    this.plugin = plugin;
    this.qm = qm;
}
```

Otherwise (by definition) one will be `null`.

Also,

```
public String getConfigString()
{
    return System.out.println("test");
}
```

isn't legal code because [`PrintStream.println()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28%29) is `void` (and [`System.out`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) is a `PrintStream`). You can use something like

```
String str = "test";
System.out.println(str);
return str;
```

Comment: How would I make QuickMethods a variable in my main class to be with the constructor when registering the class with the constructor.

Comment: @JarFile By creating an instance of `QuickMethods`? `QuickMethods qmInstance = new QuickMethods();` would create a reference to an instance of `QuickMethods`.